# Facebook shared url with blank image

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-share, facebook-tag

I have problem with Facebook-sharing my page with visible image.

Address is: http://www.fotomachina.pl/steosoft/test/test2/

When I share it on Facebook title and description shows correctly but instead of image there is blank white space.

What's wrong? Below my tags used in  of the website:

```
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.fotomachina.pl/steosoft/test/test2/gif/2017_07_19_14_06_10_small.jpg" />    
    <meta property="og:title" content="Test Page Title test" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Test Page" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fotomachina.pl/steosoft/test/test2" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Test Page Description Content test" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.fotomachina.pl/steosoft/test/test2/gif/2017_07_19_14_06_10_small.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="750" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="563" />
    <meta property="article:author" content="https://facebook.com/fotomachina" />
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cache on server was causing problems. Question is irrelevant.